# Can't weld overlapping UV's

Tags: uv, edit-mode, uv-image-editor

I have 2 identical islands stacked together. Blender doesn't merge the vertices that are in the exact same position when I use *Remove Doubles* or *Weld*. It only works when the vertices are NOT in the same exact position.

Here's a GIF:

[image: GIF animation of the problem]

Comment: Why would you want to merge vertices in the UV editor?

Comment: When you have 1 islands instead of 2, it's easier to manage the UV layout. I'd have to only press `L` to select everything instead of box selecting everything with `B`

Comment: You can only link 2 UV islands when they are separated by a UV seam in 3D space...

Comment: Like I showed in the GIF, I can weld the vertices if they're separated. It only stops working when both vertices are in the exact same position. You can weld any vertex if that condition is met. I just tested it.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this, and even after doing the welding, most of the time, it is temporary (maybe I am doing something wrong - Oh Well).

Regardless of this, the easiest solution to this is to turn on proportional editing <kbd>O</kbd>, and scroll the influence area way down. This way when I move one vert, then everything directly under/over my active vertex comes along for the ride.

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure that "Limit selection to visible" is unchecked, it should select vertices that are hidden behind others.

[image: Limit selection to visible]

Comment: Sorry, I just saw this was for UV and not mesh. Feel free to ignore this.